# Trial unavailable: You’ve already had a trial of Watson Studio on this computer. How to Solve this?

Tags: watson-studio

I have a 'IBM Watson Studio Desktop Academic Trial' which is valid till June 17, 2020. I am getting the above message while launching the Watson Studio. Please let me know how to resolve it.

Contacted IBM Digital Commerce Site Support and they redirected me here.

Comment: Then they did wrong. This isn’t their customer support for licensing and installation. I’d suggest contacting them again

Answer (score 0):

Id used to login to Watson studio needs to be checked in back-end system to ensure it is active.

Answer (score 0):

We checked the backend, we see 2 accounts are using the same machine. To fix this issue, you need to move first user's subscription to a different machine (logout and login on a different machine). Please let us know if this info helps.